# How to create the documentation of laravel project?

Tags: laravel

I have a simple website on Laravel with different types of entries and categories.
I need to create documentation for him.
I tried to install phpDocumentor, but it is not installed on Laravel latest version.
Also I should clarify that this is not the API of the project a simple website.
What other solutions do you have for automatically generating documentation?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create documentation for routes, you can try [laravel-routes](https://github.com/GussRw/Documentation-Laravel-Routes).

This package can be installed with composer with the next command:

```
composer require gussrw/laravel-routes
```

You can generate the HTML file from the console with the next artisan command.

```
php artisan route:docs
```

This command creates an HTML file in Project/docs.

**Route description**

The description is optional, but if you want to add them create a PHP comment over each route in the web.php file with @description.

```
/**
 * @description Show the home page of the site
 */
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index') -> name('home.index');
```

**Resources routes**

The descriptions in the resource type routes are identified by their method in the controller.

```
/**
 * @index Show the main view
 * @create Show the view to create a photo
 * @store Save a photo in database
 * @edit Show the view to edit a photo
 * @update Update photo data in database
 * @destroy Delete a photo in database
 */
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

**Params**

Routes params are defined with @param name Description, you can use @param in resource type routes.

```
/**
 * @description Download photo with the photo id.
 * @param id ID of the photo in database
 */
Route::get('/photo/{id}/download', 'PhotoController@download');
```

Comment: the @description content is not shown in the routes.html view. any solution for that